# How to disable button as soon as its clicked

Tags: android, button

I have a button which on Click loads another activity, but before it loads another Activity if i tap it continuously, then it launches the activity but the same activity is loaded two times or more.
I have tried button.setEnabled(false) soon after button.setOnClickListener...onClick
but that is not disabling the button, i am also logging a text as soon as the button is tapped, thus depending on my taps it logs the text 2 or 3 times even if i had tapped it 10 times.
What i feel here is before the button can listen to tap events, i am tapping it so fast that it listens to all those events as many times as i tap it.

Thus i need something where the button can just listen one tap and then disable it.

please help

Comment: button.setEnabled(false); should work when you are enabling it again ?

Comment: setEnabled(false) won't work because it is too late. The button click events are already in the queue.

Comment: what's wrong with (instead of introducing a variable) just doing this (pseudo code):
`code`
onClick(v)
  if (btn.isEnabled()) {
    btn.setEnabled(false);
    // do stuff
  }
// end onClick
`code`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its known issue.Basically u can set the flag.

```
int flag=1;

 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
           {

                if(flag)
                 {
                   button.setEnabled(false);
                   Log.d("ins", "called");
                 }
                flag=0;
            }
```

Comment: I thought here flag type should be boolean or you need to check `if(flag == 1)`

Answer (score 4):

more preferred solution is,

```
onclick(){
  btn.setEnabled(false);
  btn.setClickable(false);
  //yourwork
  myWork();
}

myWork(){
 //your tasks.
 btn.setEnabled(true);
 btn.setClickable(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be considered as an android-bug. You are right with your assumption, that the click-event is caught by the system, and may be provided too late, if one clicks continuously on a clickable. You can try to get around this problem by inserting a `boolean` value like this

```
private boolean handledClick = false;

public void onClick(View v){
    if (!handledClick){
        handledClick = true;
        startActivity(...);
    }
}
```

this will ensure, that even if `onClick` is triggered more that once, the Code inside gets executed only once...

Comment: Just make sure that you reenable the button (by setting handledClick back to false) at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar problem but I was able to disable the button in the `onClick()` callback method of the listener by using button.setEnabled(false) of the button. I enable the button at the `onResume()`, `onRestart()` and `onWindowFocusChanged()` of the activity that has the button.

And I assume this is one of the way to disallow user to tap a button (continuously).

Comment: setEnabled(false) won't work because it is too late. The button click events are already in the queue.

Comment: @DavidWasser the problem statement requires that the button click should happen once. So as you pointed out the click event will be in the queue the first time but if we disable it(using setEnabled(false)), having this code as the first line of `onClick()`, it will not allow the click to happen the second time.

Comment: No, actually that's not what happens. If the user presses the buton 5 times very quickly, the Android framework will put 5 onClick events in the message queue. When the first event gets delivered to the onClick() method, then the button will be disabled, but by then the damage is already done. I've seen this a million times. You can't reliably solve this problem with setEnabled().

Comment: @DavidWasser so what is your proposed solution?

Comment: @bman look at the accepted answer. You need to remember that the user clicked the button by setting a `boolean` variable. Then, in the `onClick()` method, you just ignore the action if the flag has already been set (this means that the user has already executed the action, whatever it is). Once the action has been successfully executed, you can reset the `boolean` variable to `false` to allow the user to click it again (if this is appropriate to the workflow of your application).

Comment: @bman The important thing to remember is that clicking a button doesn't immediately cause a call to `onClick()`, it just adds the event to a queue to be executed later. Because of this, if the user is really quick (or the phone or your application is slow to respond), then the event can be added to the queue multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If go refers to the button you need,

```
 go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
    //    your code here
          go.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

EDIT: Since it still queues up, how about.

```
s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            s.setEnabled(false);
            if(flag == 1){
                flag=0;
                //your code here
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: YA i have specified i am using this as u have used but in-spite of using go.setEnabled(false) it is not getting disabled.
go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
    //    your code here
          go.setEnabled(false);

        }
    });

Comment: setEnabled(false) won't work because it is too late. The button click events are already in the queue.

Comment: YA i have specified i am using this as u have used but in-spite of using go.setEnabled(false) it is not getting disabled.
go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
    //    your code here
          go.setEnabled(false);
//lot of other codes goes here then....
          Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("xyz","abc");
intent.putExtra("jjjd","dddd");
intent.putExtra("szdsd","abssdc");
intent.putExtra("xadasyz","afdsafsbc");
startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and this is how I solved it :

```
int flag = 1;

 private OnClickListener btnNextActivity = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {

            if(flag){
          Intent nextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NextActivity.class);
          nextActivity.setClassName(". . .",". . ." );
          . . .
          startActivity(nextActivity);
          flag = 0;
            }

           else{
            Show Toast Message Here
              }
      }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Button.setEnabled(true/false)` like this :

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.isEnabled()) {
                v.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

---

You can also check `Button` is enabled or not by calling `Button.isEnabled()`.

---

For More about `Button` [Read This…](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)