# Unwanted click events in Android after showing a dialog

Tags: android, events, user-interface, click, galaxy

**CONTEXT**:

- I have a simple ListActivity (call it "**Activity<sub>1</sub>**") that contains a ListView and a number of menu items.
- Clicking an item in the ListView shows a popup dialog.
- Clicking a menu item button (let's call it "**Button**") in the ActionBar starts an Activity (let's call it "**Activity<sub>2</sub>**") using `startActivityForResult()`

**PROBLEM**: If the user touches a ListView item, generating an `onListItemClick()` event in the ListActivity and then really quickly touches Button, a `onOptionsItemSelected()` event is posted to the message queue and processed in due course. This results in the following odd behaviour:

1. User touches ListView item
2. User touches **Button**
3. User sees dialog generated by `onListItemClick()` for a split second
4. **Activity<sub>2</sub>** started by `onOptionsItemSelected()` starts over top of the dialog
5. When user finishes with the **Activity<sub>2</sub>**, he returns back to the dialog, not right back to **Activity<sub>1</sub>**

This is very odd and unsettling. In my experience doing UIs in older GUI frameworks, the GUI framework never allowed the second event to post to the queue so you never had to worry about these things.

**QUESTION**: Is there a "preferred" design pattern to prevent the user from being able to press **Button** and have it start **Activity<sub>2</sub>** when my app is already in the process of showing a dialog in response to the ListView item select?

Disable the entire **Activity<sub>1</sub>** view hierarchy until the dialog ends??

Comment: RATS. This looks like a dupe of [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5608720/1911388) and [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077728/how-to-prevent-the-activity-from-loading-twice-on-pressing-the-button) where people are trying to suppress "double clicks" on buttons.

Comment: Here's another post dealing with the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11031814/1911388.

Answer (score 0):

Write in your ToS that users with 2 thumbs per hand should use the app with caution.
More seriously, maybe you can check if your dialog is open before starting your activity with either a boolean or [Dialog.isShowing()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#isShowing%28%29)