# Button clicking opens the new activity repeatedly on clicking the button repeat. How to avoid this

Tags: android, button, android-intent

I'm very new to Android development. In my app I using one dialog box to submit one form.Button after submit the button when clicking the button only once it's working perfect. But I keep on clicking it got submitted repeatedly and open the new activity repeatedly. For solving this issues I using intent flags like. But the issue still there. The following is the code for submitting the dialog box.

```
private void report_abuse(final String report_text) {
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
    final String user_id = user.get("uid");
    final String token = user.get("token");
    Intent get_id = getIntent();
    final String profile_id = get_id.getStringExtra("reg_id");

    String tag_string_req = "req_register";

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
    URL_REPORT_ABUSE, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    Intent to_profile = new Intent(ProfileView.this, ProfileView.class);
                    to_profile.putExtra("reg_id", profile_id);
                    startActivity(to_profile);
                    finish();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "report submit successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //hideDialog();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("user_id", user_id);
        params.put("profile_id", profile_id);
        params.put("message", report_text);
        return params;
    }
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map headers = new HashMap();
        headers.put("Client-Service", "app-client");
        headers.put("Auth-Key", "123321");
        headers.put("Token", token);
        headers.put("User-Id", user_id);
        return headers;
    }
};
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
});
mBuilder.setView(mView);
AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
dialog.show();
}
});
```

Comment: you can do it by disabling the button after the first click.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11031952/7505436)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call view.setClickable(false) to your view that you are clicking after first click.

Comment: where i have to call view.setClickable(false) means,inside Onclicklistener.

Comment: Yes, you can do like view.setClickable(false) inside OnClick(View view)